# Vierbeins in General Relativty; degrees of freedom?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry

I am self-learning GR.

**I want to ask if vierbeins $e^b_{\ \ \nu}$ need to satisfy any relations or if I am free to choose any type of vierbein I like**

So I have been looking into tetrads again. I understand I can calculate $g_{\mu \nu}=e^a_{\ \ \mu}e^b_{\ \ \nu}\eta_{a b}$ and use it to transform into a *local tetrad frame*, hence simplifying some equations.

The great thing I learned about this is that when I transform into a locally minkowskian frame, I can use special relativistic formulas to calculate some quantities. Yet I can not find a source telling me how to choose the vierbein. Am I free to choose **any** vierbein which satisfies $g_{\mu \nu}=e^a_{\ \ \mu}e^b_{\ \ \nu}\eta_{a b}$?

*Small note:* I have not studied differential geometry :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You are free to choose any such vierbein. Note that any two choices of vierbeins are related by a local Lorentz transformation. This appears then as a gauge symmetry in tetrad formalism. By choosing a particular veilbein, you have essentially fixed the gauge.