# What are the degrees of freedom of the vierbein?

Tags: general-relativity

If the metric tensor $g^{ab}$ is symmetric it can have D(D+1)/2 degree of freedom.

If it is written in terms of the vierbein $g^{ab} = e^a_n e_n^b$ then does the viebein have $D^2$ degrees of freedom since there is no requirement for it to be symmetric?

Or are two vierbeins the same if rotated e.g. $e' = e.M$ where M is an $O(D)$ matrix?

What does this mean exactly in terms of physics?

Comment: Who writes $g^{ab} = e^a_n e^b_n$? The proper expansion of the metric into a vielbein is $g  = g_{ab} e^a e^b = g_{ab} e^a_{\mu} e^b_{\nu} \mathrm{d}x^\mu\mathrm{d}x^\nu$.

Comment: Aside from the actual question here being unclear because you seem to be using a non-standard idea of vielbein/vierbein, the title question is a duplicate of [Vierbeins in General Relativty; degrees of freedom?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/243925/50583)

Comment: The OP is using a basis of contravariant vectors mutually orthonormal  with respect to an Euclidean metric. It is not usual, but is coherent: a, b are componet indices, more usually named $\mu, \nu $, and $n $ in the label denoting different vectors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A vierbein in a point of a manifold is an orthonormal basis with respect to a given metric. You denoted by $e_n $ the generic vector of such a basis. So $n $ distinguishes between different vectors of that basis. The components $^a $ of each fixed vector are referred to a basis of the tangent space associated to some coordinate system and do not play any role in this discussion. 
The degrees of freedom therefore are  exactly the parameters of the connected Lie group connecting two generic orthonormal bases. This is because, given an orthonormal basis, the only orthogonal transformation leaving it invariant is the identity and every other orthonormal basis can be reached from the initially given basis   by a suitable orthogonal transformation. The parameters of $SO(D) $ are $D (D-1)/2$ which is the dimension of the real space of antisymmetric matrices $D\times D $, the Lie algebra of $SO (D) $.